# Chaining MapReduce jobs in unit tests (mrunit 1.1.0)

Tags: java, unit-testing, hadoop, powermock, mrunit

I have a mapreduce process that has 2 mapper/reducer pairs chained together.

How can I go about unit-testing the whole chain?

I've looked into the MapReduceDriver and can't seem to figure out how to pipe the output of the first job into the second.

Thanks

Comment: You could chain the jobs really, only in junit you couldn't. right?

Comment: There used to be a PipelineMapReduceDriver for the old Hadoop API for doing that but I can't seem to find the equivalent in the new API.